# how to use EOF as prime read in cc

Tags: c

why the while loop starts executing infinite if I enter any alphabet and when I enter any number it executes only once.
Scanf("%d",&a) function returns 1 for any number and 0 for any character or string. As I know EOF is not equal to 1 and 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main
{
    int a;
    while(scanf("%d",&a) != EOF)
    {
        printf("hi devender \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: man scanf(3) *These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the error.* - **from the man pages**

Comment: @peter - wrong. "%d" provides conversion for `int`. If a non-digit is encountered, a ***matching failure*** occurs and character extraction from the input buffer ***ceases*** leaving the offending character ***unread*** resulting in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
// input buffer==> 42foo\n
scanf("%d", &a); // returns 1 (not EOF), a is now 42
// input buffer==> foo\n
scanf("%d", &a); // returns 0 (not EOF), see comments about a
// input buffer==> foo\n  // no change
scanf("%d", &a); // returns 0 (not EOF)
// input buffer==> foo\n  // no change
scanf("%d", &a); // returns 0 (not EOF)
// input buffer==> foo\n  // no change
... ... infinite loop
```

In short, don't compare the return value from `scanf()` with EOF; compare with the number of expected assignments.

```
if (scanf("%d%s%d%d", &a, name, &b, &c) != 4) /* error */;
```

Comment: `// input buffer==> foo\n` `scanf("%d", &a); // returns 0` --> I'd expect `a` remains 42 and does not become _indeterminate_.  Had `scanf()` returned `EOF` due to input error, then `a` would be _indeterminate_.

Comment: @chux: I had the idea `a` might change inside `scanf()` but can't justify it (or the opposite). I'll take out that part of the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the `scanf()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (bolding mine):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, these functions return the number of input items
>   successfully matched and assigned; **this can be fewer than provided
>   for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure**.

If you don't enter a number, you get a matching failure and `scanf()`  returns zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but to understand that the problem with the infinite loop is that the buffer is not empty, try this code.

## include

```
int main(void)
{
    int a,c;
    while(scanf("%d",&a) !=EOF)
        {
            printf("hi devender \n");
            while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' ) ; //empty the buffer
        }
    printf("Finished");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why the while loop starts executing infinite if I enter any alphabet
>
> `scanf("%d",&a)` function returns 1 for any number and 0 for any character or string. As I know EOF is not equal to 1 and 0

It appears the key issues for OP is that on a matching failure, the text in `stdin` is not consumed.  So once an `"abc\n"` is entered. the `'a'` and the rest, remain in `stdin` until some other input function reads it.  As code lacks other ways to read data, we have an infinite loop.

---

A common work-around it to read the offending character

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int scan_count;
  int a;
  while((scan_count = scanf("%d",&a)) != EOF) {
    if (scan_count == 0) {
      getchar();
    }
    printf("hi devender \n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Or as others suggest, consume to the end of the line of input.